# GTK+3 replacing/swapping pixbuf seems to break

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have a simple GTK3 grid layout using images as buttons and I want to replace the images when various things happen.

What's weird is that this works fine if I replace/remove the image from the same piece of code each time but not when I alternate between the two different sources despite (as far as I can see) everything being almost identical.

**Anyway, here's my code...**

Initial setup - create pixbuf, make it an image, attach it to the button - this works fine:

```
/*
 * Initial setup
 *
 * dbp is a pointer to a struct that contains the button, the pixbuf, etc.
 */

// Create new blank (&transprent) image
dbp->pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, TRUE, 8, innerButton.width, innerButton.height);
gdk_pixbuf_fill(dbp->pixbuf, 0x00000000);

// Image holds pixbuf
dbp->image = (GtkImage*)gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(dbp->pixbuf);

// Attach image to button
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn), GTK_WIDGET(dbp->image));

// Attach button to grid
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(_grid), dbp->btn, c, r, 1, 1);
```

Clear image code - blanks the image (transparent):

```
gdk_pixbuf_fill(dbp->pixbuf, 0x00000000);
```

Button refresh callback (updates image from pixbuf):

```
if(dbp->image_modified != 0)
{
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(dbp->image), dbp->pixbuf);
    dbp->image_modified = 0;
}
```

1st image replacement code - takes data input in our own format & creates new pixbuf:

```
GdkPixbuf *newpixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, TRUE, 8, BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT);
g_object_unref(dbp->pixbuf);
// <Data unpacked to pixels here, code removed for clarity>
dbp->pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_copy(newpixbuf);
gdk_pixbuf_copy_options(newpixbuf , dbp->pixbuf);
dbp->image_modified = 1; // Trigger refresh
```

2nd image replacement - loads image from file and creates new pixbuf:

```
GdkPixbuf *newpixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale (file_path, BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT, FALSE, &err);
// [Error check code removed for clarity]
g_object_unref(dbp->pixbuf);
dbp->pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_copy(newpixbuf );
gdk_pixbuf_copy_options(newpixbuf , dbp->pixbuf);
dbp->image_modified = 1; // Trigger refresh
```

Now, if I do repeated calls to these routines I get odd interactions;

If I do `clear`, `image_replace_1`, `clear`, `image_replace_1`, `clear`, `image_replace_1` etc... it works absolutely perfectly.

If I do `clear`, `image_replace_2`, `clear`, `image_replace_2`, `clear`, `image_replace_2` etc... it works absolutely perfectly.

**However, when I do:**

If I do `clear`, `image_replace_1`, `clear`, `image_replace_2`, `clear`, `image_replace_1`... it falls over with complaints that `GDK_IS_PIXBUF(pixbuf) failed` and I can't for the life of me work out how that happens?

I have also tried this alternative code for the button refresh callback;

```
dbp->image = (GtkImage*)gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(dbp->pixbuf);
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn), GTK_WIDGET(dbp->image));
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: Do you ensure that all these functions are only called from main GTK thread?

Comment: The refresh callback is on a loop from a `g_timeout_add()` call, the button modification functions are triggered by a `g_socket_service`, they all share a global context containing the struct that contains the buttons, pixbufs, etc.

Comment: What does this man wrt `g_socket_service`? Is that callback executed in the same thread? If not, you might forward the task to main thread via `g_idle_add` or similar. You modify the context variable and this might not be thread safe.

Comment: It's mostly inherited code (and I'm new to GTK) but I don't think it's multi-threaded, it just services incoming requests in a loop and then periodically updates the buttons if a callback has been registered (if that's the correct term) - I can't see any fork()s in the code or similr calls. Also, the tests that fail are done so slowly that any change has plenty of time to propagate without risk of race-hazards etc.

Comment: Does it fail immediately when a certain callback is entered first? Or after n iterations? Or after random number of callbacks?

Comment: There is also a chance that your problem is not in the code you show. Please provide a minimum compilable example to reproduce.

Comment: I'm trying to build a more accurate picture of the steps to failure, it always throws an error on the button refresh callback when it's failed but ia also think sometimes the `image_replace_n` code falls over the `pixbuf` too.

Comment: I'll try to generate a minimum compilable example but it could take a while to untangle all the other stuff going on / retain a meaningful data-set to load the different image formats.

Comment: Well I might have fixed it while poking around - it seems it has to do with the size of the pixbuf and the image being loaded into it, the different routines were scaling it differently, even though the pixbuf was being unref'd and replaced each time it still somehow caused a problem. Now I scale both to the same dimensions and it seems reliable - I won't pretend to understand GTK well enough to know the reason.